# SSL certificate termination using AKS approuting add-on gives K8S fake cert instead of actual

Tags: azure-aks

I'm trying to setup a simple hello-world app in AKS with SSL termination.  I've followed these guides to the letter...

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing-dns-ssl

... everything looks fine but when I browse to the site, it always just gives me the K8S Fake Certificate instead of the certificate I've uploaded to keyvault.

The secret exists and I can pull out tls.crt and tls.key, decode them and it is the correct certificate:

```
$ kubectl describe secret
Name:         keyvault-aks-helloworld
Namespace:    hello-web-app-routing
Labels:       secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/managed=true
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  1155 bytes
tls.key:  1679 bytes
```

This is what my ingress looks like and seem to include the correct TLS config and annotation:

```
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             aks-helloworld
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        hello-web-app-routing
Address:          1.2.3.4
Ingress Class:    webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  keyvault-aks-helloworld terminates mydomain.com
Rules:
  Host          Path  Backends
  ----          ----  --------
  mydomain.com
                /   aks-helloworld:80 (10.1.2.3:80)
Annotations:    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: https://myvault.azure.net/certificates/mycert
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    20m (x2 over 21m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    20m (x2 over 21m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

It feels like the certificate is there but isn't correctly attached to the ingress.  However, if I disable the certificate in keyvault and then decribe the ingress again, I do get an error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                            From                      Message
  ----     ------       ----                           ----                      -------
  Warning  FailedMount  <invalid>                      aks-app-routing-operator  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod hello-web-app-routing/keyvault-aks-helloworld-6f8f6446d8-j6q99, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount objects, error: failed to get objectType:secret, objectName:mycert, objectVersion:: keyvault.BaseClient#GetSecret: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="Operation get is not allowed on a disabled secret." InnerError={"code":"SecretDisabled"}
```

If I re-enable and recreate the ingress, the error goes away and it seems happy.  I just can't get anything other than the K8S Fake Certficate!

At a bit of a loss and there isn't much documentation on SSL termination using the approuting add-on specifically.

Comment: Check if the certificate is correctly imported into [azure key vault](https://i.imgur.com/gSxoIBx.png) and the correct version is being used. You can use the az keyvault certificate show command to verify this. Check if the certificate is correctly mounted into the pod and the correct volume is being used. You can use the kubectl describe pod command to verify this.

Comment: Btw, the error related to the failed mount when the secret in Key Vault is disabled suggests that the CSI (Container Storage Interface) Secrets Store driver is involved in synchronizing your Key Vault secret with the Kubernetes secret. Ensure that the [CSI](https://i.imgur.com/AZLfXru.png) driver is correctly installed and configured in your AKS cluster.